# How do I get the url in io.socket.on("connection") in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I tried the followings but it does not return the url as string.

```
 io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.handshake.url)
})
```

it prints something like "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M5blR4u". How do I get a url like "http://192.168.2.1:3600/app"?

Do I really have to send the url from the user side with window.location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `socket.handshake.headers.host`

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log(socket.handshake.headers.host)  
});
```

and the output is:

`localhost:8560`

or you can use `handshake.referer` that will do the trick.

For more detail: [Socket.io Documents](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-handshake)

Comment: Hey. How can I get the string after this? I mean e.g. in my example the "/app"?

Comment: why do you need the string after that because socket application does not have any routing? As you are running socket with the express app, express routers are totally separate.

Comment: Cause I want the io.on("connection") react differently as I clicked different page. So I got it from handshake.referer. I suppose it should be the answer I want?

Comment: Thnx! I think handshake.referer should be it!